# Organizing Lines into Arrays Based on First Value in the List

Tags: python, list, arraylist

I just started learning python for data analytics for my project. I read each line of my file and created lists of the values for each line, and now I want to add lines into arrays based on the first value in the line. I want to create 4 separate arrays based on the first value in the line (1, 2, 3, or 4). Anything will help, I'm not used to this yet!

This is what I have so far that works:

```
with open('/Users/ameliajennings/Downloads/data_example.txt') as f:
line = f.readline() 
while line:
    mylist = line.split(",")
    print (mylist)
    line = f.readline()
```

This is what I tried to isolate all of the rows that start with 1, but it doesn't work:

```
with open('/Users/ameliajennings/Downloads/data_example.txt') as f:
line = f.readline() 
while line:
    mylist = line.split(",")
    if mylist == 1: 
        print (mylist)
    line = f.readline()
```

Comment: Maybe you could try to *initialize* a dictionary first and read the line to put into array.

Comment: @DanielHao I just started learning python today I dont even know what that means lol

Comment: @DanielHao ['1', '14:29:8', '24.93', '25.22\n']
['2', '14:29:8', '0', '400', '16818\n']
['3', '14:29:8', '400', '0\n']
['4', '14:29:8', '750', '216', '36', '18', '0', '0\n'] here's what the lines look like

Answer (score 0):

When you split the line by "," mylist variable will be in type of list. So if you want to isolate / detect rows that start with "1" the code should be as follow:

```
with open('/Users/ameliajennings/Downloads/data_example.txt') as f:
line = f.readline() 
while line:
    mylist = line.split(",") # string split to array by seperator ','
    if mylist[0] == 1: # Take the first array item
        print (mylist)
    line = f.readline()
```